# Next.js SSR with Firebase Auth to authenticate external API using Axios interceptor

Tags: firebase, axios, firebase-authentication, next.js

My Next.js SSR App will use Firebase Auth to authenticate users. The access token from Firebase Auth will be used to authenticate on an external API.

I have it working in my React App but I am migrating now to Next.js for SSR.

Currently I am struggling with the Axios interceptor... how do I authenticate the user and add the Firebase access token to the request header when on server-side?

I think I need to use cookies?!

High level explanation would sufficient, some code example even better!

**edit:** I found this [article](https://colinhacks.com/essays/nextjs-firebase-authentication) but that would mean I have to add this logic to every single protected route and additionally add the access token to the Axios interceptor for client-side requests, eg. when searching or sending a post request?

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx: GetServerSidePropsContext) => {
  try {
    const cookies = nookies.get(ctx);
    const token = await firebaseAdmin.auth().verifyIdToken(cookies.token);

    // the user is authenticated!
    const { uid, email } = token;

    // FETCH STUFF HERE!! 

    return {
      props: { message: `Your email is ${email} and your UID is ${uid}.` },
    };
  } catch (err) {
    // either the `token` cookie didn't exist
    // or token verification failed
    // either way: redirect to the login page
    ctx.res.writeHead(302, { Location: '/login' });
    ctx.res.end();

    // `as never` prevents inference issues
    // with InferGetServerSidePropsType.
    // The props returned here don't matter because we've
    // already redirected the user.
    return { props: {} as never };
  }
};
```

Comment: Hello, I recently implemented this in a Nuxt app (Vue) using the recommended approach from the Firebase team using service workers. I would suggest checking this article: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/service-worker-sessions

Comment: thanks @Stf_F will check this out! Is your project open source by any chance? Would love to see how you implemented this using Nuxt. Is it Nuxt 3?

Comment: Hi Julie, the project is not open source unfortunately and was made with Nuxt 2. Maye have a look at this repo: https://github.com/nuxt-community/firebase-module/tree/master/packages/firebase-module/lib/plugins/services. It is a Nuxt plugin that handles all the integration of firebase services in a nuxt app, including the whole Auth/SSR part.